# Form multiplies Inline

Tags: php, html

I've bumped into a small problem that i cant seem to find the fix for.

I've got this simple form with a textarea, no biggie.
The problem shows when i edit a post i've already got in the database.

So, i retrieve the varchar field i have in my database and inserts it into my form by default.
If this is what i got by default:

```
this is some default text
with a line break
```

now, if i just saves this without doing any changes, this is what i get in the PHP $_POST variable:

```
this is some default text

with a line break
```

the /n character seem to multiply by itself. The next time i save the text the /n multiply again, giving me 4 /n in a row and so on.

It doesn't make any sense to me.

Step 1. I pre-fill the textarea with the contents mentioned in the first gray box above

Step 2. I submit the same content

Step 3. I run the following code before i do anything else:

```
echo '<pre>'. $_POST['content'] .'</pre>'; die;
```

Step 4. The newline are multiplied as in the second gray box above

Comment: Can you please add some more information how you retrieve and set the content? Without any code we can not help you.

Comment: @Oliver
I don't see what more information i can give you.

Step 1. I pre-fill the textarea with the contents
Step 2. I submit the same content
Step 3. I run the following code before i do anything else: echo '<pre>'. $_POST['content'] .'</pre>';
Step 4. The newline are multiplied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy.

there is some code in your application, that doubles line breaks. Just find it and get rid of it. Not a big deal.

(If you don't trust me, as you obviously do, create a simple testing script consists of just form and nothing else and see)

Comment: seems like there could be a bug (feature?) in the framework i'm using.

Answer (score -1):

Wild guess: Windows `CR LF` line breaks.

In Windows, if you type a line break, they consist of not only `\n`, but `\r\n`. If MySQL implicitly converts `\r` to `\n` when inserting/updating, this would explain this behaviour.

Try removing any occurences of `\r` in the PHP first and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi pdinklag, 
it's not the MySQL that is the problem really. The second i submit the form and retrieves the data with the PHP $_POST the extra lines are there, before i start handling the data.

Answer (score -1):

Remove line break using [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: This is in incomplete answer.  You can do better!